# Ajax post in coldfusion page with email not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

A little new to JQuery and Ajax, but I have a simple mail form that I am trying to post using JQUERY to keep the page from reloading.

Here is the sample page: DetailInfo.cfm.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() { $("#frmSubmit").submit(sendForm) });     

function SubmitForm()
{
Tbody = document.getElementById("txtBody");

if(Tbody.value == '')
    alert('Please enter some text for your message.');
else
{               
    $("#frmSubmit").submit(sendForm);
              //frmSubmit.submit();             
}
}           

function sendForm() 
{               
    $.post('DetailInfo.cfm',$("#frmSubmit").serialize(),function(data,status){      
        $("#result").html(data)
    });
    alert('Email Sent');
    return false
}       
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<cfif isdefined("form.txtBody")>
    <CFMAIL TO=somedued@place.com
     FROM=anotherplace@some.com
     SUBJECT= "Thank you for submitting the information">Message below sent from user #Session.UserID# , the info to be updated is the following:

     #form.txtBody#

     </CFMAIL> 

 <cfelse>

    <form method="post" name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" action="DetailInfo.cfm">
                            <table id="tblError" name="tblError" >          
                            <tr><td colspan="2" class="ui-widget-content" align="center">Suggested Detail to Submit</td></tr>
                             <tr><td colspan="2" class="ui-widget-content">System does not recognize detail. Please provide a suggested name. Click Send when done.</td></tr>
                             <tr><td colspan="2" class="ui-widget-content" valign="top">Comments: </td></tr>
                             <tr><td class="ui-widget-content" ><textarea cols="75" rows="5" id="txtBody" name="txtBody" class="ui-widget-content"></textarea></td><td class="ui-widget-content" ><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Send" class="ui-widget-content" align="middle" onclick="SubmitForm();" /></td></tr>
                     <tr><td  class="ui-widget-content" colspan="2" align="center"><div id="dvMessage"></div></td></tr>
                     </table></form>  
  </cfif>                     
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this method cause this page is going to open up ideally in a modal window, which I don't want the parent page disappearing when I post.  Also just for testing I hardcoded email to and from addresses.

The problem is when I call a normal submit through the commented out line:

```
frmSubmit.submit();
```

The form posts the email and I get it.  However I am trying to use the method above instead, and when I click Send, nothing happens visually (which is fine) but the email does not get sent.

I can't seem to get this to fire through the code of

```
$("#frmSubmit").submit(sendForm);
```

Another suggestion I was told was to use the PreventDefault but I tried that in a few places in the code and that didn't work.

Any idea as to why the email is not going out?  Much help appreciated.  This is a real simple page that should work as far as I am concerned, but my JQuery and AJAX experience is a little limited as to why this isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: Are you making an AJAX post to the same .cfm file?

Comment: Seems odd, why use ajax if the logic is in the same file.  I would put the email logic in a cfc if you want to call it by ajax

Comment: Scott, uh... I guess so?  It's posting to the same page as you can see.  Lance I am using this method cause the page is to open in a modal window and the post if it was done the other way would cause the parent form to disappear.  I want the page to stay loaded, while it posts.  If there is a better method to do this, feel free to let me know.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 pages, form.cfm for the form, and action.cfm for action (send the email when called by ajax from the form page).

Here is the code for your form.cfm

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        function SubmitForm(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "action.cfm",
                data: $( "#frmSubmit" ).serialize(),
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data, status) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });

        };

    </script>

    <title>Email Test</title>

</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" action="DetailInfo.cfm">
        <table id="tblError" name="tblError" >          
            <tr><td colspan="2" class="ui-widget-content" align="center">Suggested Detail to Submit</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" class="ui-widget-content">System does not recognize detail. Please provide a suggested name. Click Send when done.</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" class="ui-widget-content" valign="top">Comments: </td></tr>
            <tr><td class="ui-widget-content" ><textarea cols="75" rows="5" id="txtBody" name="txtBody" class="ui-widget-content"></textarea></td><td class="ui-widget-content" ><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Send" class="ui-widget-content" align="middle" onclick="SubmitForm();" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td  class="ui-widget-content" colspan="2" align="center"><div id="dvMessage"></div></td></tr>
        </table>

    </form>                     

</body>

</html>
```

and here is the code for action.cfm

```
<cfsilent>
    <cfmail to="somedued@place.com" from="anotherplace@some.com" subject="Thank you for submitting the information">

        #form.txtBody#

    </cfmail>
    <cfset data = "email sent OK" />
</cfsilent><cfoutput>#data#</cfoutput>
```